# NodeJs tcp socket connection not working on live server

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

i'm trying to connect to my nodeJs app through socket, my problem is my code works fine in local server but same code is not connecting on live server.

server socket

```
 const HOST = 'app.domain.com';
 const PORT = 3000;
    const server = net.createServer();
     server.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
        this.output('Running On PORT: '+PORT+"   HOST: "+HOST)
});

    let sockets = [];
server.on('connection', function(sock) {
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ' : ' + sock.remotePort)
   
    sockets.push(sock);

    sock.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('DATA  => ' + data);
        // Write the data back to all the connected, the client will receive it as data from the server
            sock.write("Response : "+new Date());
           // console.log("Sending Socket Response")
    });

    // Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
   sock.on('close', (data) => {
       let index = sockets.findIndex(function(o) {
            return o.remoteAddress === sock.remoteAddress && o.remotePort === sock.remotePort;
        })
        if (index !== -1) sockets.splice(index, 1);
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ' ' + sock.remotePort);
    });

});

 }
```

NodeJs scoket client

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = 'app.domain.com';
var PORT = 3000;

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
  console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
  // Write a message to the socket as soon as the client is connected, the server will receive it as message from the client
 client.write('I am Chuck Norris!');

});

// Add a 'data' event handler for the client socket
// data is what the server sent to this socket
client.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('DATA: ' + data);
  // Close the client socket completely
  client.destroy();
});

// Add a 'close' event handler for the client socket
client.on('close', function() {
  console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

When i run this script on live server my client socket keep showing timeout error without connection for once.
I have also confirmed from my server log that socket server starts successfully.